# Create dictionary from registered variable from different hosts

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-facts

I've got a task that tells me if a port is open or not on a list of hosts with a netstat:

```yaml
- name: who is listening on port 5555
  shell: netstat -paunt | grep 5555
  register: test
  ignore_errors: true
```

So I have a variable that contain, for each host this value:

```
ok: [host1 -> localhost] => {
    "msg": "tcp        0      0 XX.XX.XX.XX:5555      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   "
}
```

What I would like to do, is to get all the not empty vars named test to be concatenated
in a single dictionary.
But I don't find how to do it. Is it even possible to do so with ansible?

The finality is for me to create a dynamic dictionary of IP with this port open and I will pick a random one from the dictionary to do a test on.

I want to create a single dictionary from all the registered var named "test" that contain a result from the "who is listening on port 5555" tasks.

For now I am trying to create my dictionary by doing:

```yaml
- name: fact
  set_fact:
      ip: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ test.stdout }}"
  when: test.stdout |length > 0
```

but it's not creating a dictionary that contain the result from all hosts.
it creates a dictionary by host containing his result only.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you want to do? Also write the `python` code that you have tried so far.

Comment: all host facts are accessible from anywhere in `hostvars['name in inventory']`. Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

Comment: what i would like to do is to create a single dictionary or list that contain the IP to which the specific port is binded, from all  all my hosts.Some of them don't have that port open, that's why i want to create the list or dictionary dynamically. The main goal is to do a test that involved this specific port on a random IP from the list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of the below example (not tested as is but on similar data structure).

- All the facts registered for every hosts are available in the `hostvars` dictionary (one key entry for every hosts, named after their name in inventory. See [ansible special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)).
- You can transform a dict into a list of key/value pairs with the [`dict2items` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter).
- You can use [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) to select all elements having an existing `value.test` and rewrite the list with each element being `{key: host, value: <value of stdout of test var>}`
- You can then use [`items2dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#items2dict-filter) to revert the filtered and transformed key/value list to a dictionary.

The following play (to run after your actual value harvesting) should give you what you expect:

```yaml
- name: Consolidate test result in a single dict
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Show the result
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            hostvars
            | dict2items
            | json_query("[?value.test].{key: key, value: value.test.stdout}")
            | items2dict
          }}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. it seem's to do as intended but i unfortunatly can't use it yet for the reason that i can only use ansible 2.4 and dict2items and items2dict are introduce in 2.7 and 2.8.

Comment: Ansible 2.4 is very old. What prevents you from installing the version you need in your environment (install as user with pip, use a python virtualenv...)?

Comment: i know but it's unfortunately not my decision, i must only use tools approved by the groups. As i understand, in ansible 2,4, i won't be able to do it the easy way. so i will create temps file on each machines with the result of the netstat, then fetch it from my ansible server and consolidate a single file that i will exploit then. But i will keep your solution to improve my playbook when they'll approved newer version of ansible.